# ffmpeg: concatenate videos of different frame rates?

Tags: ffmpeg

I store some N number of videos in a text file `list.txt` like so:

```
file /tmp/eef3e563eb32.mp4
file /tmp/video_152.mp4
file /tmp/video_153.mp4
file /tmp/video_154.mp4
file /tmp/video_155.mp4
```

The `video_` files are 30fps, the others are 60fps. When I try to concatenate them doing:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
    -loglevel panic \
    -y \
    -f concat \
    -safe 0 \
    -an \
    -i /tmp/list.txt \
    "out.mp4"
```

The `out.mp4` plays the 60ps one (first) fine, then the 30fps ones are all 2x speed.

How can I resolve this? Can I add options in `list.txt` or do I need a more complex solution with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: See the answer in the linked Q. Apply the same video_track_timescale value to all inputs.

Comment: Is there . away to apply video_track_timescale within the text file per line?

Comment: Not at present.

Comment: After applying the same timescale of 60k to both,  I have two clips one with `fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)` and one with `fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)` and concatenating them does not yield same speeds in QT. any thoughts?